# chain rule of $\frac{d^ny(p(t))}{dt}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In the book, "Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equation by Agarwal," it says that derivative of $$\frac{d^ny}{dt}(p(t)) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}p_{ni}(t)\frac{d^iy}{dt}$$
where $p_{ni}(t)$ are some suitable functions. But, I can't see how can it happen? Can anyone explain for me why is that?

Comment: To prove it use induction. Assume the formula holds for all $k=1,2,3,\ldots,n$ and use $\frac{d^{n+1}y(p(t))}{dt^{n+1}} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{d^{n}y(p(t))}{dt^{n}}$ to prove that the formula holds for $k=n+1$. For the base-case $n=1$ the standard chain-rule gives us $\frac{dy(p(t))}{dt} = \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{x=p(t)} p'(t)$ (so we can take $p_{10} = 0$ and $p_{11} = p'(t)$).

Comment: yes, it is. I just fixed it, thank you for pointing out